# How to send properties in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

I need to create a Trail and this trail has sub trails and the subtrails has levels, I have three DropDownList. where trails has one dropdown and same subtrails and levels.

The problem is when I attempt to create a new Trail, because the dropdown has a TrailId to show the all trails existing, depending which trail is selected, an ajax is ran for filtering the subtrails and show single sub trails depending trail selected.

This view is when creating:

[View Creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8eWr.png)
This code is the view:

```
@model DefinityFirst.Mobile.Admin.Web.Services.Marvel.Contracts.ListTrailSubTrailLevelContract
@inject DefinityFirst.Mobile.Admin.Web.Services.Marvel.IMarvelServices DropDownDataHelper

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> @Html.ValidationMessage("Error")
    </div>
}
<h2>Create</h2>
<p>New TrailSubTRailLEvel</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("TrailSubTrailLevel", "TrailSubTrailLevel", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "demoForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Trail</h4>

        <div class="form-group" id="divOne">
            @Html.Label("", "Trail", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10" id="partialDiv">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TrailId, await DropDownDataHelper.GetTrailsDdl(), "Select one", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()" })

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrailId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("", "SubTrail", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @name = "Subtrail", @id = "Subtrail" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownList("SubTrailId", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a SubTrail", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SubtrailId", @name = "SubtrailId" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubtrailId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("", "Level", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @name = "Level", @id = "Level" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LevelId, await DropDownDataHelper.LevelsDdl(), "Select one", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LevelId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>




        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#SubtrailId').hide();
        $('#LevelId').hide();
        $("#Subtrail").hide();
        $("#Level").hide();

        $('#TrailId').on('change', function () {

            if (this.value != 0) {
                $("#Subtrail").show();
                $('#SubtrailId').show();



            } else {
                $('#SubtrailId').hide();
                $('#LevelId').hide(); 
            }
        })
        $('#SubtrailId').on('change', function () {

            if (this.value != 0) {

                $("#Level").show();
                $('#LevelId').show();


            } else {

                $('#LevelId').hide();

            }
        })

    </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var URL = 'http://localhost:51514/api/TrailSubTrailLevel/JSonSubTrails';
        var dllDropDownSubTrail = $('#SubtrailId');
        var dllDropDownTrail = $('#TrailId').val();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#TrailId').change(function () {
                $('#SubtrailId').html("");
                var val = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: URL,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var myData = data.Value;
                        localStorage.setItem('myList', myData);

                        $.each(myData, function (key, value) {
                            if (value.TrailId == $('#TrailId').val()) {
                                console.log(value.Name)
                                $('#SubtrailId').append('<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.Name + '</option>');
                            }
                        });
                    },

                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('ERROR', data.Value);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>



}
```

this code is where received action of click in button create, send information all DropDownList:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ListTrailSubTrailLevelContract ListTrailSubTrailLevelContract)
{


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _marvelServices.CreateTrailSubTrailLevel(ListTrailSubTrailLevelContract);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "TrailSubTrailLevel");
    }


    return View(ListTrailSubTrailLevelContract);
}
```

And this code is where that properties sending, but  I need alone this propertie "TrailSubTrailId", because in my table alone exists two properties "LevelId" and "TrailSubtrailId", but I sending three properties and this is start the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DefinityFirst.Mobile.Admin.Web.Services.Marvel.Contracts
{
    public class ListTrailSubTrailLevelContract
    {

        public int id { get; set; }

        public int TrailId { get; set; }

        public string TrailName { get; set; }

        public int SubtrailId { get; set; }

        public string SubTrailName { get; set; }

        public int LevelId { get; set; }

        public string LevelName { get; set; }

        public int TrailSubtrailId { get; set;  }

    }
}
```

THIS PART IS WHERE CONSUMING SERVICE

This code is TrailSubTrailContract:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DefinityFirst.CarrerPath.Model.Contracts
{
    public class TrailSubTrailLevelContract
    {
        public TrailSubTrailLevelContract()
        {
            //Level = new HashSet<LevelContract>();
            //TrailSubtrail = new HashSet<TrailsSubTrailsListContract>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int TrailSubtrailId { get; set; }

        public int LevelId { get; set; }

        public TrailsSubTrailsListContract TrailSubtrail { get; set; }

        public LevelContract Level { get; set; }
    }
}
```